# How to create signature for twitter in Salesforce and what are the steps for signature creation

Tags: twitter, oauth

I need a signature for my first request to twitter :

My code create a Post request for this end Url https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token and I have to set a header which is mention below in which I need signature.

I have only call back Url, consumer_key. I have created nonce and timestamp. I need signature.

Authorization Header:
OAuth oauth_nonce="XXXXXXXXX", oauth_callback="XXXX", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="XXXXXX", oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXX", oauth_signature="HOW I CREATE THIS", oauth_version="1.0"

Answer (score 0):

You can use oauth module https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth

```
   var oauth=require('oauth');         
   var consumer = new oauth.OAuth(
     "https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", 
_twitterConsumerKey, _twitterConsumerSecret, "1.0A", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/sessions/callback", "HMAC-SHA1");
```

then generating signature like this :

```
    var parameters = consumer._prepareParameters("user_access_token", "user_access_token_secret", "http_method", "request_url");
    var headers = consumer._buildAuthorizationHeaders(parameters);
```

parameters array contains signature, also you can build authorization headers if needed. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

I think twitter has a nicely written document on creating a signature.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature

Check it out...

Edit: I noticed your oauth_* parameters are not in order.
Don't forget to get them in order.

Comment: I would love to see a comment about why was my answer marked as not useful. Question is on how to create Oauth signature, and what would be better than twitter's documentation itself. I can't post code unless person asking question posts some details himself.
Stackoverflow is full of self educated idiots.